# Why will .replace not work inside .map

Tags: javascript, regex, dictionary, replace

I have a regular expression I am using to replace two escaped characters. I can replace them by directly accessing them but cannot with the map function. Can someone please explain what I am misunderstanding?

```
var entry = [ '\n000087',
  '1',
  '000055555',
  'admin',
  '1',
  '0',
  '2018/07/06',
  '08:53:14\t' ];

entry = entry.map((item)=>{
    return item.replace('/\\(?:[a-z])/g','');
});
console.log(entry);//does not remove \n or \t
console.log(entry[0].replace('/\\(?:[a-z])/g','')); // does remove \n
```

Comment: well you do not have a regular expression.... You have a string. Remove the quotes `.replace(/\\(?:[a-z])/g,'');`

Comment: `\t` is a single character, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation). Whether you use `map` or not is irrelevant here.

Comment: Try return item.replace(/[\t\n]/g,'');

Comment: Thank you for telling me to remove quotes. I'm interested as to why this would work with quotes and the regex i used when only operating on one string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. As people have mentioned, you don't use the proper regex syntax. My code simply removes newlines and tabs.

```
var entry = [ '\n000087',
  '1',
  '000055555',
  'admin',
  '1',
  '0',
  '2018/07/06',
  '08:53:14\t' ];

entry = entry.map((item)=>{
    return item.replace(/[\t\n]+/g,'');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What was wrong with my regex syntax besides me passing it as a string? i **thought** that I was saying match a forward slash and the first [a-z] character.

Comment: Well, \n and \t are special escape characters and they are not in the [a-z] set.